# Running Macro through VBScript and bring to front (Top window)

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

Looking for some help with a VBScript i have thrown together. It works, which is great but just trying to add that finishing touch.

So what i need is for the script to be shown on top of all other windows open. Excel is hidden but there is a progress bar that does show, however it's hidden behind everything.

I just honestly don't have the knowledge here.

Here is what it looks like

```
ExcelFilePath = "***\Merging Tool.xlsm"
MacroPath = "UpdateOversightBD"
Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
ExcelApp.Visible = False
ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = False
Set wb = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFilePath)
ExcelApp.Run MacroPath
wb.Close False
ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = True
ExcelApp.Quit
MsgBox "Oversight Backing Data Was Created Successfully At " & TimeValue(Now), vbInformation
```

Comment: Where does the progress bar come from?

Comment: Progress bar is a userform.

Comment: A `UserForm` inside the Excel macro being executed from VBScript?